# I cant seem to include one html page into another?

Tags: html, jquery

I have researched and found out that I have to use jquery to add html pages into another, but when i tried it on my end it wasn't working. I am running it on a local host as well...

```
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#header").load("header.html");
  });
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/aboutMe.css" type="text/css" />
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Play&display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

<div class="header"></div>
```

Comment: `$("#header")` selects an element with the **ID** of `header`. Your example however, only has an element with the **class** of `header`, e.g. `<div class="header"></div>
`

Comment: So either change `class="header"` to `id="header"` or change `#header` to `.header`.